# How to remove eventHandler from Designer automatically

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010

When I create an eventHandler (for example dblClick on a button) VS creates related line of code in the Form1.Designer file.
When I delete that button - the code remains in the Designer, giving me an error during debuging.
Could someone explain what is the reason for such an behaviour, and how could I remove that lines automatically.

Comment: When I remove a button from a form, all related code in the Form1.Designer.cs is removed. What _does_ stay is the event handler method in Form1.cs, but that doesn't generate compiler errors.

Comment: Maybe, there is some options settings. Or because- my VS2010 is an Express Edition ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just re-open it, and it should disappear, if dosen't check agian, you probably didnt delte the button